# Adobe Illustrator: Save-forWeb-jpeg looking different

Tags: adobe-illustrator, save, jpg

When saving my artwork as a `.jpeg` (using the Save-for-Web-option) the saved file looks different than the artwork inside Illustrator. Specifically, the order of some of the layers seems to have been changed, for no apparent reason. The images below show what is happening.
Has anyone else encountered this issue and can tell me what excatly is going on here?

Artwork inside Adobe Illustrator:
[image: Artwork inside Adobe Illustrator]

Artwork after having been saved as `.jpeg`:
[image: Artwork after jpeg-export]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hum. Wellcome to the complicated world of color transitions.

It is a little difficult to know exactly.

The first thing would see is if all the colors are in the same color mode. RGB or CMYK.

Then what values of black you have. For this kind of things it is better to leave all in RGB.

[image]

There are other things, what color profiles you are working with, if the ilustrator is simulating a CMYK output, blending modes...

One thing you could try is to flatten your image inside Ilustrator before exporting. Make a copy of the file first, so you do not accidentally save the flattened copy.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you have any transparencies going on there or not but to preserve transparency you need to save as .png